# How to find sub entity from id

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have an entity like;

```
@Table
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected String id;

    //some other fields, getters, setters

}
```

and two sub-entities like

```
@Table
@Entity
public class Teacher extends Person {
     //some fields, getters, setter
}

@Table
@Entity
public class Student extends Person {
     //some fields, getters, setter
}
```

Is it possible to find a given id belongs to Person, Teacher or Student without selecting all entity?

**NOTE:** Main entity and sub-entities have a lot of fields and I just want to figure out which type is it? For now I do;

```
Class clazz = entityManager.find(Person.class, id).getClass().
```

But it loads whole entity which I don't want. Also I know, I can write a query and select only ids from each entity but it works only with this example. I have many entites like this and I want to write more generic way to find the sub-class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write a query like e.g. `select type(p) from Person p` to determine the type

Comment: yess, that is the solution. thank you very much